# Using geom_segment to create a timeline visualization

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to create a chart like this one produced in the [NYTimes](https://www.nytimes.com/interactive/2017/09/24/world/europe/merkel-germany-election-twelve-years.html) using ggplot:

[image: Timeline visualization]

I think I'm getting close, but I'm not quite sure how to separate out some of my data so I get the right view. My data is political office holders that appear something like this:

```
name,year_elected,year_left,years_in_office,type,party
Person 1,1969,1969,1,Candidate,Unknown
Person 2,1969,1971,2,Candidate,Unknown
Person 3,1969,1973,4,Candidate,Unknown
Person 4,1969,1973,4,Candidate,Unknown
Person 5,1971,1974,3,Candidate,Unknown
Person 1,1971,1976,5,Candidate,Unknown
Person 2,1971,1980,9,Candidate,Unknown
Person 6,1973,1978,5,Candidate,Unknown
Person 7,1973,1980,7,Candidate,Unknown
Person 8,1975,1980,5,Candidate,Unknown
Person 9,1977,1978,1,Candidate,Unknown
```

And I've used the below code to get very close to this view, but I *think* an issue I'm running into is either drawing segments incorrectly (e.g., I don't seem to have a single segment for each candidate), or segments are overlapping/stacking. The key issue I'm running into is my list of office holders is around 60, but my chart is only drawing around 28 lines.

```
library(googlesheets)
library(tidyverse)

# I'm reading from a Google Spreadsheet
data <- gs_title("Council Members")
data_sj <- gs_read(ss = data, ws = "Sheet1")

ggplot(data, aes(year_elected, years_in_office)) +
  geom_segment(aes(x = year_elected, y = 0, 
                   xend = year_left, yend = years_in_office)) +
  theme_minimal()
```

The above code gives me:

[image: Timeline chart]

Thanks ahead of time for any pointers!

Comment: Two ways to handle overlapping. 1) use actual election and departure dates, rather than binning to the integer year. 2) Use semitransparent lines with end markers to show each person. For the vertical segments, use the same technique as 1), so that when someone entered and left office in the same year, there's still two different x values for them.

Comment: @JasonHeppler do you have exact dates (not rounded to year)?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. Unfortunately I don't have exact dates, but I also worry the problem might persist even if I did since these are city council seats and there are moments where a group of members are voted out or voted in at the same time. That might continue to cause the problem I'm seeing.

Comment: I suppose I could rig my own kind of "jitter" and just add a bit of day or month padding between repeat years. I just hoped there was some way around this that didn't mean messing with the data in strange ways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your data frame is called `d`, then:

- Transform it to `data.table`
- Add jitter to `year_electer`
- Add equivalent jitter to `year_left`
- Add group (as an example) to color your samples

Use `ggrepel` to add text if there are many points.

Code:

```
library(data.table)
library(ggplot2)
library(ggrepel)

d[, year_elected2 := jitter(year_elected)]
d[, year_left2 := year_left + year_elected2 - year_elected + 0.01]
d[, group := TRUE]
d[factor(years_in_office %/% 9) == 1, group := FALSE]

ggplot(d, aes(year_elected2, years_in_office)) +
    geom_segment(aes(x = year_elected2, xend = year_left2,
                     y = 0, yend = years_in_office, linetype = group),
                 alpha = 0.8, size = 1, color = "grey") +
    geom_point(aes(year_left2), color = "black", size = 3.3) +
    geom_point(aes(year_left2, color = group), size = 2.3) +
    geom_text_repel(aes(year_left2, label = name), ) +
    scale_colour_brewer(guide = FALSE, palette = "Dark2") +
    scale_linetype_manual(guide = FALSE, values = c(2, 1)) +
    labs(x = "Year elected",
         y = "Years on office") +
    theme_minimal(base_size = 10)
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! That seems to have done the trick. I adapted it slight to make it more `tidyverse` friendly using `mutate` instead of subsetting (but to the same effect).

Answer (score 1):

For the record and to address my comment on @PoGibas answer above, here's my `tidyverse` version:

```
data_transform <- data_sj %>% 
  mutate(year_elected_jitter = jitter(year_elected)) %>% 
  mutate(year_left_jitter = year_left + year_elected_jitter - year_elected + 0.01)

ggplot(data_transform, aes(year_elected, years_in_office, label = name)) +
  geom_segment(aes(x = year_elected_jitter, y = 0, xend = year_left_jitter, yend = years_in_office, color = gender), size = 0.3) +
  geom_text_repel(aes(year_left_jitter, label = name)) +
  theme_minimal()
```